# Recursion for $p_n$ with coefficients that depend on $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, recursion

I have the recursion

\begin{align}
p_0 &= a_0, \\
p_n &= a_n + \sum_{m = 0}^{n - 1} b_{n - m} p_m, \quad n \ge 1.
\end{align}

I have explicit expressions for $\{ a_n \}$ and $\{ b_n \}$, but they are not easy to work with. Is there an explicit solution for $p_n$ or does the existence of an explicit solution depend on the specific form of $\{ a_n \}$ and $\{ b_n \}$?

For what it is worth, the $p_n$ are probabilities that satisfy $0 < p_n < 1$ and $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty p_n = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following formal power series $p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n x^n$, $a(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, and $b(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n$, where $b_n=0$. Then $p(x)=a(x)+p(x)b(x)$. It can happen that for some $r>0$ these formal series are convergent (for any $|x|<r$) Taylor series for the functions $p(x)$, $a(x)$, and $b(x)$, respectively, and that $p(x)$ is a Taylor series for a function $\frac {a(x)}{1-b(x)}$.